# How to load a xml file in google chrome using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm beginner in web programming and new in this site. I'm trying to get the content of xml tags but When I open the code below in chrome, nothing appears. Can someone give me a hint, please? 
Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script> 
var xmlDoc, xmlHttp;
function readxml()
{
    xmlHttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET","books.xml",false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML.documentElement;
    return xmlDoc;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var xmld
xmld=readxml();

document.write(xmld.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>");
document.write(xmld.getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>");
document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("year")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the function `readxml` returns before the xml is loaded. Therefore you are trying to write the XML's content to the document before you have it.

Check out the `reqListener` in this example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest